# watch database and wait for changes in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

i have a messaging system app and every message has some status in it with 3 types of done , in progress,not started so when i send a message to user B its not started for example so when user B receive the message he changes the status to in progress here i want to send a notification to the sender and the admin that the status has been changed how can i monitor database for changes and when it changes it generates some specific notification and send it . here is the migration of message table

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->string('body');
        $table->integer('status');
        $table->integer('sender_id');
        $table->integer('receiver_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initiate a `Message` model class to represent the records in your `messages` table and then listen for the `updating` or `updated` event on that model, which fires everytime a record has been updated or is currently updating. There you can check if the updated property is the needed one (in your case - `status`) and execute the code you desire. I suggest you check the documentation on how to work with eloquent models (if you haven't yet) and look up the provided events. That should do the work.
Here is the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events)

Comment: i have a model for it already can you guide me which parts of the documentation i must read cause i cant find that part to watch database :)

Comment: How to handle database transactions in case if we are using updating or updated event

Comment: @SoubhagyaKumarBarik What do you exactly mean? :D

Comment: example: 
we have to run 2 queries and those are in transactions. Let's say the first query is executed but the second is not now it will roll back the first one right. In that case how to deal

Comment: Laravel eloquent event won't wait for transaction commit

Answer (score 3):

Please check https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers
There are some events which you need (`Update`,`Updated`,`Saved`)